# .NET Core 1.0 read form-data posted file and put it in MultipartFormDataContent

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to fetch form-data sent to .NET Core API. The aim is to redirect the post request to another API.

I don't want the file to be stored locally but only "transmitted" again in a request.

Here is the code I'm trying.

```
MultipartFormDataContent multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

multipartContent.Add(new StringContent(Request.Form["id"]), "id");

var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
if (file.Length > 0)
{
    var fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(Request.Form.Files[0].OpenReadStream());
    multipartContent.Add(fileStreamContent, Request.Form.Files[0].FileName);

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://example.com:8000");

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/document/upload", multipartContent);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        retValue = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<DocumentUploadResult>();
    }
}
```

It seems `Request.Form.Files[0].OpenReadStream()` doesn't work, as the request received by remote api is empty. The openReadStream was suggested by VS2015 as the former .FileStream i used before .NET Core seems not to be present anymore.

**Is my idea to try to create a StreamContent from the file actually a good idea? Is there any better type I could use to transmit my file accepted by  MultripartFormDataContent?**

Answer (score 2):

In order to read a file from a form post, have your Action accept an `IFormFile` parameter:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file){

        byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
        using (var reader = file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            await reader.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
        }
 }
```

Comment: How to put the result of this file read into `MultipartFormDataContent` to be able to pass it to my next post request?